# App to expand 'Other' category when selected on picker from a form (SwiftUI))

Tags: swift, forms, swiftui, picker

I want to provide the user with a list of categories (via picker included in a form) and the last category listed is 'Other'. If the user selects 'Other', the app is to add a field to the form for the user to enter in the new category name (which would be saved for future references).

I have been able to have the picker list presented:

```
Section {
    Picker(selection: $courseIndex, label: Text("Course")) {
        ForEach(0 ..< courses.count) {
            Text(self.courses[$0]).tag($0)
        } //ForEach
    } // Picker                    
} // Section - Course
```

But I am unable to determine how to have the new field presented for the user to enter in the new category.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `.onChange(of: VAR)` and if other is selected, enable a flag for the new section, but there is probably a better way

Answer (score 0):

You can add use `if` in the BodyBuilder, example:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var courseIndex: Int = 2
    
    let courses = ["Course 1", "Course 2", "Other"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Section {
                Picker(selection: $courseIndex, label: Text("Course")) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< courses.count) {
                        Text(self.courses[$0]).tag($0)
                    }
                }
            }
        
            if courseIndex == 2 {
                Text("Show Extra")
            }
        }
    }
}
```